The ambiguous [webrequest] tag is misused quite a bit
The webrequest tag is for .NET webrequest, but it's been misused for unrelated topics:

The webRequest API for WebExtensions / Chrome extensions
generic/abstract network request on the web platform

Suggesting to add a tag like maybe web-extension-webrequest and retag the questions listed below. Not sure what to do about the "abstract/generic web request" meaning.

63 questions for webrequest + javascript are either about generic network requests or chrome extensions, see the three lists below
34 questions for webrequest + google-chrome-extension
1 question for webrequest + firefox-addon (same as "google-chrome-extension" conceptually)

List A. Using webrequest in a generic sense of "a network request":

Is it possible to get the request headers in a request?
Node.js webrequest (http) stopping after several seconds
Send Webrequest via JavaScript to Openproject
Send Header in window.location.href while redirecting to another page
Run Selenium IDE test case on web request
Call Javascript Function from VBA without IE Window
How can we call Availity API
How to populate a ListView in NativeScript with JSON Data from a WebService?
Secure Javascript code

List B. Questions about chrome extensions without the google-chrome-extension tag:

chrome.webrequest in a event listener function
chrome.pageAction.setIcon does not work reliably
How exactly does the following Chrome Extension javascript code snippet work?
Chrome extension Web Request doesn't show info
Chrome extension - read web request body content
How to create extension for block & storing searched URL's using javascript
How to get URLs of page's requests?
Unblocking url using webRequest API by removing the listener which has blocked it

List C. Questions about Firefox extensions without the firefox-addon-webextensions tag:

webRequest.getSecurityInfo() does not work


Other than [tag:webrequest] there's also: [tag:httpwebrequest], [tag:ftpwebrequest] and [tag:system.net.httpwebrequest]. Except the last one all of the others are named ambiguously, and should have a prefix (perhaps similar to the last one). In fact [tag:httpwebrequest] and [tag:system.net.httpwebrequest] are about the same thing.

If it's too broad and ambiguous (eg list A), why not just remove it? Or retag to [tag:http-request] if relevant.

"The webrequest tag is for .NET webrequest ..." Perhaps disambiguate webrequest by renaming it to .net-webrequest or, if that's not possible, creating a new tag .net-webrequest, then alias webrequest to it. The cleanup still remains the cleanup, either way.

@Nanigashi: Rename would be much better, since we don't want webrequest to show up as an auto-completion that people could select without reading the mouseover; It would only change to .net-webrequest after posting, and low-effort posters might not even look at the tags again.

The tag as it is, is ambiguous yes, and the way to solve such ambiguity is to not have a webrequest tag at all. There are many things called "webrequest" in different contexts that are just some kind of network request. The Chrome webrequest api already has a tag google-chrome-extension which covers all the questions about the api exposed to extensions.
In a website about questions about programming, webrequest as a generic concept shouldn't exists as topic. It's would be like having a programming tag, a good 20% of all questions relate to making or processing network requests, so askers would apply it to everything.
The plan should be remove webrequest tag, while retagging when appropriate if the correct tag isn't used.
